# How to add a validation characteristics/rule?

Tags: python, validation

I try slove exercise from hacerrank [Click](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-credit-card-number)
I don't know how to add these rules:
► It may have digits in groups of 4, separated by one hyphen "-".
 
► It must NOT have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits.

Here is my code:

```
how_many=1 #This version for tests, Here will be input() 
for i in range(how_many):
    string=input()
    formated_str=''.join(string.split('-', 4))
    if (char.isdigit() for char in formated_str) and len(formated_str)==16 and (formated_str[0]=='4' or formated_str[0]=='5' or formated_str[0]=='6'):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

Problems:

I don't know that `formated_str=''.join(string.split('-', 4))` will be work like they want, I mean "► It may have digits in groups of 4, separated by one hyphen "-"." And how to implementation this second rule ?

Answer (score 2):

The function below first deletes your `-` inside your code string and then check for digit repetition. The regex is the following `r"\d*(\d)\1{3,}\d*"`. 
If the regex matches, so the code is not valid and the function returns `False`. Otherwise, the function splits the original code string and then it checks the length of each substring.

```
import re

string   = "2134-4444-4412-3241"
string1  = "2134-4344-4412-3241"
string2  = "2134-4342-4412-3241"

def isValid(aString):
    pattern = r"\d*(\d)\1{3,}\d*"
    isValid = True

    rep_string = aString.replace('-', "")
    print(rep_string)
    if (not re.search(pattern, rep_string)):
        splitted = string.split('-')
        for split in splitted:
            if (len(split)!=4):
                return(False)
        return(isValid)
    else:
        return(False)

print(isValid(string))
print(isValid(string1))
print(isValid(string2))
```

I hope that this solution will help you. This piece of code will give you the following output:

```
False
False
True
```